# CouchDB httpd_global_handlers for hosting static files at root

Tags: couchdb

I was trying to do something tricky with CouchDB v1.5 the other day and I ended up breaking something:

I modified the httpd_global_handlers section for the root URL from the stock value:

```
[httpd_global_handlers]
/ = {couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_welcome_req, <<"Welcome">>}
```

to this modified value:

```
[httpd_global_handlers]
/ = {couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_utils_dir_req, "/home/pokstad/www"}
```

But when I went to the root URL, I get this error message:

```
{"error":"unknown_error","reason":"function_clause"}
```

Is it not possible to host static files at root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the source. So let's dive in 
(If you are not familiar with erlang it will be a bit tough to follow but I will try my best to explain it). [The misc handlers section](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/1.5.x/src/couchdb/couch_httpd_misc_handlers.erl#L66)

```
handle_utils_dir_req(#httpd{method='GET'}=Req, DocumentRoot) ->
"/" ++ UrlPath = couch_httpd:path(Req),
case couch_httpd:partition(UrlPath) of
{_ActionKey, "/", RelativePath} ->
    % GET /_utils/path or GET /_utils/
    CachingHeaders =
            [{"Cache-Control", "private, must-revalidate"}],
    couch_httpd:serve_file(Req, RelativePath, DocumentRoot, CachingHeaders);
{_ActionKey, "", _RelativePath} ->
    % GET /_utils
    RedirectPath = couch_httpd:path(Req) ++ "/",
    couch_httpd:send_redirect(Req, RedirectPath)
end;
handle_utils_dir_req(Req, _) ->
send_method_not_allowed(Req, "GET,HEAD").
```

The relevant piece of code here is this part

```
    case couch_httpd:partition(UrlPath) of
{_ActionKey, "/", RelativePath} ->
    % GET /_utils/path or GET /_utils/
    CachingHeaders =
            [{"Cache-Control", "private, must-revalidate"}],
    couch_httpd:serve_file(Req, RelativePath, DocumentRoot, CachingHeaders);
{_ActionKey, "", _RelativePath} ->
    % GET /_utils
    RedirectPath = couch_httpd:path(Req) ++ "/",
    couch_httpd:send_redirect(Req, RedirectPath)
end;
```

what this here says is if there is a '/' in the url perform

`couch_httpd:serve_file(Req, RelativePath, DocumentRoot, CachingHeaders);`
action.

otherwise just append a '/' to the supplied and redirect it. Now what you have done with your config entries looks
harmless enough. But there is a key piece to this puzzle that is still missing. `couch_httpd:partition(UrlPath)`.
Which is just a wrapper around the [mochiweb utility](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochiweb_util.erl#L40),mochiweb is the http server that is used by couchdb. Here are  the comments of the code

```
%% @spec partition(String, Sep) -> {String, [], []} | {Prefix, Sep, Postfix}
%% @doc Inspired by Python 2.5's str.partition:
%% partition("foo/bar", "/") = {"foo", "/", "bar"},
%%  partition("foo", "/") = {"foo", "", ""}.
```

so a call to `partition("","/")` returns {"","",""}(You can test this yourself by compiling mochiweb_util.erl and testing with mochiweb_util:partition("/","/"). etc)

Now back to our handle_utils_dir_req. After the case statement it receives an empty string without '/'. The clause ' {_ActionKey, "", _RelativePath}' and 
it appends the '/' to the path and issues a redirect to localhost:5984//. You can test this in a browser or curl

> curl -v http://127.0.0.1.:5984/
>
> Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
>
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
>
> Connected to 127.0.0.1. (127.0.0.1) port 5984 (#0)
>
> GET / HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
>
> Host: 127.0.0.1.:5984
>
> Accept: */*
>
> **HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently**
>
> Server CouchDB/1.5.0 (Erlang OTP/R16B03) is not blacklisted
>
> Server: CouchDB/1.5.0 (Erlang OTP/R16B03)
>
> **Location: http://127.0.0.1.:5984//**
>
> Date: Tue, 10 Jun 2014 04:27:57 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1. left intact

Long story short there is no easy way to serve static html files as root from couchdb.

handle_utils_dir_req is too limiting any way since it only honors get and head request. Hope you find my answer useful.

Comment: Thank you, that was extremely useful and detailed. FYI, I've resorted to hosting static files at root by using vhosts and rewrites. Here's what I was able to do with a pure couch server: http://pokstad.com

Comment: Nice :) and a bit of a d'oh moment for me as I forgot about vhosts! I assume that you are using a vps for coucdb hosting or is your website working with shared couchdb hosts like iris couch? Also Beautiful dog :)

Comment: Thank you! It's hosted on a EC2 microserver. I experienced performance issues on Iris Couch, otherwise that would have been a good option as well. Also, Iris Couch won't allow me to host static files using handle_utils_dir_req since I don't have access to the filesystem.